# How to open locally stored html file within flyout?

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm using windows default setting flyout adding some custom commands. But now I need to open a HTML file that is stored locally ? how can I do that ?
Second thing i want to move my flyout code from app.xaml.cs to app.xaml
Any help will be appreciated
Below is my code :

```
protected override void OnInitialize(IActivatedEventArgs args){
```

SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += App_CommandsRequested;
}

```
  void App_CommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        SettingsCommand settingsCommand = new SettingsCommand(
      "About",
      "About",    
      command =>
      {
         var flyout = new SettingsFlyout();
         flyout.Title = "About";

         string file = "ms-appx-web:///assets/about/about.html";


         flyout.Show();
      }
    );
    args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(settingsCommand);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your first question, YES you can definitely open a locally stored HTML page in the Settings Flyout.

Below is the your sample which I modified a little bit:

```
private void App_CommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        SettingsCommand settingsCommand = new SettingsCommand(
             "About",
             "About",
             command =>
             {
                 var flyout = new SettingsFlyout();
                 flyout.Title = "About";

                 WebView wView = new WebView();
                 wView.Height = 700;
                 wView.Width = 300;
                 wView.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appx-web:///assets/About.html", UriKind.Absolute));

                 flyout.Content  = wView;

                 flyout.Show();
             }
           );
        args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(settingsCommand);

    }
```

Not sure of the second part of your question. Perhaps you should put a separate question.